# Количество замен в регулярке

Tags: регулярные-выражения, perl

Пусть есть синтетическая конструкция (которая полезного не делает):

```
my $T = "dfg df dfg";
my $Cnt = ($T =~ s/(df)/$1/sg);
print "$Cnt\n";
```

Выведет:

```
3
```

**Вопрос:** А есть ли какая встроенная переменная, которая будет хранить количество последних замен вот в такой конструкции как выше? Ну чтобы не использовать `$Cnt`?

Answer (score 0):

Такой переменной нет, по крайней мере в perldoc perlvar я не нашел. Но, если вы не хотите определять новую переменную, то используйте переменную "по-умолчанию", что-то вроде

```
$_ = ($s =~ s/a/b/g);
print;
```